# How can I get the actual absolute path of a file?

Tags: python, file

I need to get the absolute path of a file in python, i already tried `os.path.abspath(filename)` in my code like this:

```py
def encrypt(filename):
   with open(filename, 'rb') as toencrypt:
      content = toencrypt.read()
      content = Fernet(key).encrypt(content)
   with open(filename, "wb") as toencrypt:
      toencrypt.write(content)

def checkfolder(folder):
   for file in os.listdir(folder):
      fullpath = os.path.abspath(file)
      if file != "decrypt.py" and file != "encrypt.py" and file != "key.txt" and not os.path.isdir(file):
         print(fullpath)
         encrypt(fullpath)
      elif os.path.isdir(file) and not file.startswith("."):
         checkfolder(fullpath)
```

the problem is that `os.path.abspath(filename)` doesn't really get the absolute path, it just attach the current working directory to the filename which in this case is completely useless. how can i do this?

Comment: Perhaps include the relative path to the file in the program; relative to the program directory.  Then `abspath` will work fine.

Comment: I think you want [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath)

Comment: "it just attach the current working directory to the filename" - What else is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use: `os.path.join(folder, file)`

Comment: On most platforms, `abspath` does nearly this already. A call to `abspath` is generally the same as: `join(os.getcwd(), path)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.join(folder, folder, file)`

[Refer Link for your more knowledge](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)